# Can I tell Virtualbox to use one of my ethernet cards?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a laptop with the standard wireless and wired cards, I would like the host system to use the wireless connection and the vm machine to use the wired connection.

The point is that at the wired connection I can get a public, routable IP address, and I need that for my vm, while the host can work with the private IP.

Comment: This should be on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

You can assign any of your network cards detected by virtualbox to 1 of the 4 network cards you can put in the vm. See [this](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) for different modes

Comment: Thanks - I have read the linked document - but somehow overlooked that option in the interface.  Anyway after your answer I looked there again and found it.

Comment: No problem. Overlooking can happen!